# An up-cast for C++

Tags: c++, converting

Usually in C++, the language rules automatically widen types as necessary.  For example, I can pass a pointer-to-derived in place of a pointer-to-base, and the same with references.

There are occasions where one needs to specify a type to which a value should be coerced.  A common case of this is in the alternatives of the `?:` operator, when C++'s rules don't always determine the common type successfully.  Also, it's sometimes useful to make a pointer or reference to the const version of its type, to select the desired overload of a function.

We could use a `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` in these circumstances, but that requires more attention from reviewers to ensure that it's definitely an up-cast rather than a down-cast.  So I wrote this small function to make this easier:

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
constexpr T up_cast(std::convertible_to<T&&> auto&& value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Here's a demonstration of the simplest case I could imagine that requires it:

> ```
> struct Base {int n;};
> struct A : Base {};
> struct B : Base {};
>
> const Base& object(bool select)
> {
>     static auto const a = A{1};
>     static auto const b = B{2};
>     return select
>         ? up_cast<const Base&>(a)
>         : up_cast<const Base&>(b);
> }
> ```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the output loop of the histogram question (const char versus size_t)?

Comment: Definitely needs test cases.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, it's totally unrelated to my other question - I just happened to see this in code I've written but not had reviewed.

Comment: I probably need to spend some time with the detection idiom to create a full suite of test-cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Up-casting is not widening

> Usually in C++, the language rules automatically widen types as necessary. For example, I can pass a pointer-to-derived in place of a pointer-to-base, and the same with references.

That's not widening. Widening happens on values of primitive data types, like widening a `short` to a `long`. Converting a pointer-to-derived to a pointer-to-base is an up-cast, and the reverse a down-cast, so later on your terminology is correct.

## `std::convertible_to` is not enough

You can't just use `std::convertible_to` to check that you are doing an up-cast. As the name implies, it only checks if a conversion between the given types are allowed, and conversion can happen in many ways. Consider this slight modification of your example code:

```
struct Base {
    int n;
    Base() = default;
    Base(int): n(n) {}
};
struct A : Base {};
struct B : Base {};

const Base& object(bool select)
{
    static auto const a = A{1};
    static auto const b = 2;
    return select
        ? up_cast<const Base&>(a)
        : up_cast<const Base&>(b);
}
```

The second call to `up_cast()` would just construct a new temporary `Base` object and return a reference to that. I think you should add a [`std::derived_from`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from) clause to make sure that you are actually converting from a derived class to its base.

You should also make sure that the input and output are either references or pointers to prevent accidental slicing. Consider:

```
const Base& object(bool select)
{
    static auto const c = select
        ? up_cast<Base>(A{1})
        : up_cast<Base>(B{2});
    return c;
}
```

That will compile and do the wrong thing, and the whole point of this function is to ensure we prevent that from compiling.

## Make it easier to use

Having to remember the right cv-qualification and adding a reference is a bit annoying. I'd just want to write `up_cast<Base>(foo)` and have it return a `const Base&` or `Base&` or maybe even a `volatile Base*`, depending on what `foo` is.